# react native - DatePickerIOS with AsyncStorage

Tags: react-native

I have tried storing DatePickerIOS dates with redux. 
Is there a way to use AsyncStorage? I have been trying with no luck so far. Are there any suggestions on how to use AsyncStorage with a simple DatePickerIOS component?

```
<DatePickerIOS
  style={{ paddingTop: 110 }}
  mode='date'
  date={this.state.d}
  onDateChange={(d) => this.onDateChange(d)}
/>

constructor(props) {
 this.state = { date: newDate() };
}

onDateChange(d) {
 this.setState({
  d: d
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the state for the `d` variable in `onDateChange` but you use the `startDate` variable in the `DatePickerIO`S.
Take a look at this, didn't tested in app but should work.

```
export class PickerIOS extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      pickedDate: null
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    getData('date')
    .then((date) => {
      if (date != null)
        this.setState({pickedDate: date})
      else
        this.setState({pickedDate: new Date()})
    })
  }

  onDateChange(date) {
    setData('date', date)
    this.setState({pickedDate: date})
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <DatePickerIOS
      mode='date'
      date={this.state.pickedDate}
      onDateChange={(date) => this.onDateChange(date)}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

and then, for code organisation, in another file:

```
setData(key, data) {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, data);
    } catch (error) {
      // Error saving data
    }
}

getData(key) {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
    if (value !== null){
      return value
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Error retrieving data
  }
}
```

Comment: I want the data to persist on page refresh or navigation. That's why I wanted AsyncStorage. The 'd' and 'startdate' was a typo. I'll change that.

Comment: Take a look at my edit, all informations can be found here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html

Comment: Thanks for the help :)